# Strong Induction implies Regular Induction

Tags: induction

I want to prove that strong induction implies regular induction. Is my attempt correct:

Let $J\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be a set such that $1\in J$ and $k\in J$ for all $k<n$ implies $n\in J$. Consider the set $S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n\in J\text{ and }(k<n\to k\in J)\}$. Clearly $1\in S$ so suppose $n\in S$. Then, let $i<n+1$. Clearly either $i=n$ or $i<n$. Either way, since $k<n$ implies $k\in J$, we see that $i\in J$ but then by our assumption at the beginning it follows that $n+1\in J$ which by regular induction implies $J=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In your question title you want to show that strong induction implies "regular" induction, but the argument in the body seems to be proving that regular induction implies strong induction. Is that the intention?

Comment: I was taught that $(1\in H\wedge (n\in H\to (n+1)\in H))\to H=\mathbb{N}$ is strong induction.

Comment: x @Adam: The usual meaning of the _words_ "strong induction" is $[\forall n : (\forall k<m: k\in H)\to n\in H] \to H=\mathbb N$. (This is a stronger _claim_ because it is easier to use, because the induction hypothesis tells you more in the induction step than the induction hypothesis in regular induction does).

Comment: Beware that the usual $n\in H\to n+1\in H$ induction is "regular" only in the sense of being the induction usually taught first. "Regular" is not a technical term here, and in particular not related to "regularity" (as in the set-theoretical axiom of regularity).